# List item's position lower than container division

Tags: html, css, navigationbar

I am trying to make a navigation bar. The problem I want to solve is as you will see on running snippet, that the actual visible navigation bar is somewhat positioned lower than its container division (#navbar).

What I want is to position the navbar attached to "top" division, It could be done by relative positioning, but then what's the point of asking. :D
So any suggestions on how to fix it?

```css
body
{
    height:800px;
    width:100%;
    background-image:url("bg.jpg");
    background-repeat:repeat-x;
    
    
}

#wrap
{
    height:750px;
    width:100%;
    position:absolute;
}

#main_content
{
    position:absolute;
    width:75%;
    height:90%;
    left:12.5%;
    top:20px;
    border:groove;
    /*box-shadow:#ff3366 10px 10px 5px;*/
    background-color:white;
}

#top
{
    position:absolute;
    height:125px;
    width:100%;
    background-color:ghostwhite;
}

#title
{
    font-family:Chiller,sans-serif;
    font-size:1.8em;
    color:#f1638b;
    width:auto;
    height:inherit;
    padding-left:20px;
    float:left;
    display:inline-block;
}

#navbar1
{
    position:absolute;
    width:100%;
    top:125px;
    padding:0px;
    list-style-type:none;
    margin:0px;
}


#navbar1 li
{
   
   display:inline;
   float:left;
   
}

#navbar1 a:link,a:visited
{
    display:block;
    text-decoration:none;
    padding-left:15px;
    padding-right:15px;
    padding-top:5px;
    padding-bottom:5px;
    width:140px;
    background-color:orange;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div id="wrap">
        <div id="main_content">
            <div id="top">
                <div id="title"><h1>My Website</h1></div>
            </div>
            <div id="navbar1">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Link1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Link2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Link3</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Link4</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Link5</a></li>
            </ul>
            </div>
  
        </div>

    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I'm understanding your problem right, I believe this issue is being caused by the default margins/paddings of the list. Adding 'margin:0;' to the UL should fix it.

Comment: Also, probably add 'padding:0;' as well to align the bar to the left.

Answer (score 2):

Because you are floating the list items the parent will not contain them, they will overflow. Change the UL to `<ul class="inline-list">`

here is the `inline-list` class

```
.inline-list {
  margin: 0;
}

.inline-list:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
```

#### How it works

1. First we remove the margin that the browser gives by default to UL elements

   - `.inline-list {
       margin: 0;
     }`
2. Then we contain the floats with a **clearfix**

   - `.inline-list:after {
       content: "";
       display: table;
       clear: both;
     }`

**And here is the new demo**: http://jsbin.com/buwexe/edit?html,css,output

**Side notes about your code**:

1. Remove `display:inline` from `#navbar1 li` and instead add `list-style:none;` like so:

   `#navbar1 li {
     list-style: none;
     float:left;
   }`